# Irc Link Protect Script - Space after TLD

Tags: regex, mirc

I'm quite new to coding but i'm makin' my way through it :)

So here is my problem.

I'm using this code  which is working perfectly except this one little thingy. Links are being blocked also if it is the ending of a sentence like:

**this.com**munication works well

It should only match if there is a space/blank after the TLD.

```
on $@*:text:*:#:{
if ($regex($1-,/.+\.(ftp|thalia|com|ly|ml|gl|tk|ga|biz|co|net|org|gov|tv|edu|fm|myftp|myftp.biz)/iS)) && ($nick !isop $chan) {
          if (!$istok(%permit,$nick,32)) {
            .timerban 1 1 /msg $chan /ban $nick 
            msg $chan $Nick , posting links without permission is not allowed.
}
}
```

Maybe you guys can help me and I think i isn't a big issue but I'm searching for weeks now and can't find anything!

Big thanks in advance and sorry .. english isn't my native language.

Cheers, Marv

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
/.+\.(ftp|thalia|com|ly|ml|gl|tk|ga|biz|co|net|org|gov|tv|edu|fm|myftp|myftp.biz)( |\/|\n|\r)/iS
```

instead so it needs that the string has a space, a / or a newline.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I've found another script which works perfect for me.